# htaccess Redirect to URL with no page ID and new directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this URL.

https://www.example.com/media-center/3635-cybersecurity-data-privacy-proposed

How would I redirect to this URL with no id/hyphen and new directory name?

https://www.example.com/news-insights/cybersecurity-data-privacy-proposed

I have this code, but it doesn't change the dir name.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(media-center)/\d+-(.+)$ /$1/$2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/media-center/\d+-(.+)$ /news-insights/$1
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a new browser for testing.

Comment: This is very close. However, it redirected to this: https://www.example.com/news-insights/news/cybersecurity-data-privacy-proposed

Comment: It added /news/ to the URL

Comment: This rule won't add `/news/`. That would be due to other rules. Move this rule as your very first rule and make sure to clear your browser cache or use a new browser for testing.